# Get the items in an array in sequence then repeat?

Tags: javascript, html

```
     <img src="link" id="hof" </div> 
    <span id="myspan">Compliment: </span>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function change() {
        // ---------- Caption and images !! -----------//
        var things = ["Slide01", "Slide04", "Slide05", "Slide06"];
        var captions = ["Very nice", "Awesome", "Cool", "Best"];
        // ^^^^^^^^^^ Captions and Images !! ^^^^^^^^^^ //         

        var image = document.getElementById('hof');
        var thing = things[];
        image.src = "link" + thing + ".jpg"; // change the image   

        span = document.getElementById("myspan");
        span.innerText= "Compliment: " + captions[]; //change caption
        }
        setInterval('change()', 4000);

        </script>
```

So i am new to javascript  i am trying to make a slideshow with captions  but i need the values in the array to display in sequence like (slide01>slide02>slide03) then repeat from the start when it reaches the last value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body onload="imgcarousel()">
   <img src="" id="hof">
   <p id="caption"></p>
   <button onclick="imgcarousel()">Next</button>
</body>

<script>
    var count = 0;
    var things = ['Slide01', 'Slide04', 'Slide05', 'Slide06'] ;
    var captions = ['Very Nice','Awesome','Cool','Best'];
    function imgcarousel()
    {            
        count++;
        var img = document.getElementById("hof");
        var caption = document.getElementById("caption");
        if(count >= things.length)
            {
                count = 0;
            }            
        img.src = things[count]+".png";
        caption.innerHTML = "Compliments: " +captions[count];

    }
</script>
```

Comment: You can try the above mentioned code. What you need to include a counter to capture the button click and change image on click.

Answer (score 9):

To answer what you actually asked: You'd use an `index` variable defined *outside* `change`. Start with `0` and (after rendering the slide) increment it, wrapping around when you get to `things.length`. There's a trick for that last part:

```
index = (index + 1) % things.length;
```

Other notes:

1. Don't use parallel arrays, use an array of objects.

   ```
   var slides = [
       {name: "Slide01", caption: "Very Nice"},
       // ...
   ];
   ```

   then

   ```
   var slide = slides[index];
   image.src = "link" + slide.name + ".jpg";
   span.innerText = "Compliment: " + slide.caption + ".jpg";
   ```
2. Define that array outside `change`, there's no need to re-create it every time `change` is called.
3. Don't pass strings into `setInterval` or `setTimeout`; pass in the function instead:

   ```
   setInterval(change, 4000);
   ```
4. Consider wrapping all of your code in a *scoping function* so `index`, the array of slides, and the `change` function aren't globals:

   ```
   (function() {
       // ...your code here...
   })();
   ```

Comment: Where does this line "index = (index + 1) % slides.length; " go when creating the index variable?  How do i make the variable know when to increment after each slides?

Comment: @brand - As I said, you declare the variable outside `change` (and set it to 0). In terms of when to increment it, when do you think would make sense? Keep in mind that the first entry in an array is at index 0...